# Android emulator doesn't work on Apple M1 chip

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've  tried  to run android emulator on an `Apple M1 chip` MacBook but it doesn't work and AVD Manager shows an error with the message: **Could not start AVD**. It seems the root of this problem is that M1 chip doesn't support virtualization and AVD needs VT-x for x86 images. Most of the images are based on x86 and arm based images aren't provided for latest android versions. Is there any solution to bypass this issue? (Except using physical devices and old images)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

create AVD with **arm64** based image will help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: Here is the link to the Android Emulator Apple Silicon Preview:

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/12/android-emulator-apple-silicon-preview.html

---

They are working on it, but it will take time. I found some preview on Twitter - [Preview of Android simulator on M1](https://twitter.com/GoogleLfy/status/1332474914398322689) And some solutions will be available at the end of the year. Maby.

And good source for the following is here on Reddit: [ARM-based Macs for Android Development?](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/jrt7ph/armbased_macs_for_android_development/)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a workaround as the AVD uses Intel based API's to run the emulator, and because Apple broke up with Intel it won't work. You might just have to use a physical device or wait for a update.

That being said, there is [work](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#emulator_for_arm64_hosts) being done to support ARM based hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Good news !

**Edit on 28th July 2021**

> Apple Silicon Support

There is an **arm64** release version available for **Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1)**
You can download it here https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

<s>NDK builds doesn't work `Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64`</s>

Solved https://stackoverflow.com/a/69540773/1079990

End of beta ! Thank you