# I can't install Androidstudio on m1 mac

Tags: flutter, emulation, apple-m1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o93zw.png)

I want to install the Android studio, but in that state shown in the picture, it can't be installed anymore and it's stopped.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73366800/cannot-install-android-emulator-via-android-studio-in-macbook-m1-pro/73375509#73375509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download it manually as a zip from [Google's repository](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r21-darwin-aarch64.zip) and then install it hope that will work for you

Answer (score 0):

If that happens is your hardware incompatible. First see the hardware requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is actively being tracked at [Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242575308?pli=1).

In the meantime, you can follow [the instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive) to download an older version of the emulator.