# Mac Chip Android Studio Components Downloading takes forever

Tags: android, macos, sdk, apple-m1

[Android Setup Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhYMy.png)

Mac silicon android studio installation stuck on downloading. So I've downloaded the correct apple silicon android studio installation from their website. when trying to install the installation process gets stuck on this message:

```
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_aarch64-8807927.zip
Warning: This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying without caching.
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_aarch64-8807927.zip
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73366800/cannot-install-android-emulator-via-android-studio-in-macbook-m1-pro

Comment: Yes it does @wambo emulator working perfecrtly